# Making the List object compatible with post data from frontend in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, post

I have the following controller that I am posting to in a form via AJAX:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<int> listOfSTuff)
{
    try
    {
        service.Create(listOfSTuff);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return Json(new { gid = 7 }); // hardcoded for simplicity
}
```

I am having a hard time with my jQuery AJAX post making the `List` data type compatible with the post data.  Here is my jQuery/JavaScript code:

```
var listOfStuff = [1, 2, 3];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MyController/Create',
    data: listOfStuff,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.gid);
    },
    error: alert(':('),
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

I know that the AJAX post to the controller is working because I get a `gid` but I do not see the array elements `1` or `2` or `3` saved in the database.  It does not appear that the controller likes my JavaScript array that is being passed over.  Can anyone suggest how the data structure should look like from the frontend to make it compatible with the `List` that the controller action is expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing a critical parameter in the jQuery AJAX call that makes this work:

There is a `traditional` attribute that is `false` by default but it has to be set to `true` which uses the traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Answer (score 1):

Make your listOfStuff declared as such:

```
var listOfStuff = {postedValues: [1, 2, 3]};
```

It works better to format your posted data as a proper JSON object before posting it to the controller. so now:

`data: listOfStuff`, will post a proper JSON string

and change the parameter name in your Controller to be:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create(List<int> postedValues) 
{ 
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot and let you know how it works out.